# PHPMailer is cutting the attachement filename when it starts with a greek character

Tags: php, phpmailer

I use **PHPMailer** to attach Excel files and send them via mail.
The created files are in a form of "street address"-"month" in Greek characters.
The first problem i came up with was that the attached file's filename characters were unreadable so i changed the phpmailer class `$CharSet = 'UTF-8';` from base64.
On my localhost(XAMPP) is running good and the mail is sent with the correct filename.
But when I use the same code on Linux Server ,although the file is being created with the right filename, when i attach it, the filename is being cut until the first number,latin character or dash.
The file is as it's supposed to be in content and readable. The only problem is the filename.
e.g. Οδός - Μάρτιος --> - Μάρτιος  , 1 Οδός - Μάρτιος --> 1 Οδός - Μάρτιος

```
        ...
        $outputFileType = 'Excel2007';  
        $outputFileName = dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$address.' - '.$period.'.xlsx';
        $objWriter->save($outputFileName);
        ...
        $mail->AddAttachment($outputFileName);
```

**UPDATE 1**
After changing the **$attachment** property in **class.phpmailer.php** to public i printed the array after the AddAttachment function. I got

```
Array ( [0] => Array (   
[0] => /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/wp-content/themes/My-Theme/Reports/Οδός 1 - Μήνας 2014.xlsx  
[1] => 1 - Μήνας 2014.xlsx   
[2] => 1 - Μήνας 2014.xlsx   
[3] => base64   
[4] => application/octet-stream   
[5] =>   
[6] => attachment   
[7] => 0 ) )
```

So i guess there's something with the AddAttachment function. The path(attachment[0]) is right.

Comment: Please post how the encoded (delivered) header looks on each platform.

Comment: Have you tried `CharSet = "iso-8859-7";`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that **AddAttachment()** uses **basename()** to extract the filename from the path and basename is locale aware.
Greek users have to add `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'greek');` in the class.phpmailer.php file.